# Converting dictionary values to a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I wrote a for loop that saved the values i generated into a dictionary:

```
minThresh = d['move'].min()
minThresh = minThresh.astype(int)
maxThresh = -4
allLeverPos = {}

for i in range (minThresh,maxThresh):
    threshPos_idx = d['move']<=i
    threshPos_binary = np.array(d['move']<=i, dtype=int)
    threshCross_idx = np.where(np.diff(threshPos_binary) == 1)
    lever_thresh = len(threshCross_idx[0]) 
    allLeverPos[i]= lever_thresh
print(allLeverPos)

{-32: 1, -31: 3, -30: 122, -29: 140, -28: 170, -27: 219, -26: 238, -25: 285, -24: 315, -23: 370, -22: 433, -21: 484, -20: 528, -19: 582, -18: 638, -17: 683, -16: 728, -15: 789, -14: 845, -13: 908, -12: 1005, -11: 1057, -10: 1142, -9: 1169, -8: 1234, -7: 1277, -6: 1327, -5: 1365}
```

I'd like to use the values from the dictionary to create a list

```
list = (1, 3, 122, 140, 170...)
```

I tried doing that with this line of code:

```
x = list(allLeverPos.values())
```

However, i get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-870-67da022ee34c> in <module>
----> 1 list(allLeverPos.values())
      2 #allLeverPosList = list(allLeverPos.values())

TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not callable
```

Can someone guide me on what's going wrong / an alternate way to do this?

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. I get it if I add an extra set of parentheses `list(allLeverPos.values()())`

Comment: Apparently, `list` is somehow a `dict_values` object

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: You probably did something like `list = allLeverPos.values()` earlier, so now you can't call the `list()` function any more because you redefined it.

Comment: That's useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to extract all the values:

```
x = [value for key,value in allLeverPos.items()]
```

Comment: This seems like extra work, getting the keys and then discarding them. What's wrong with what he wrote?

Comment: You are right, there shouldn't be anything wrong with what he wrote. I am just providing an alternative.